# Wordpress Contact form 7 custom shortcodes

Tags: wordpress, shortcode, contact-form-7

Contact form 7 has some shortcodes, like [_date] to get todays date. But I want to display the date one week from now.

So I need to create a custom shortcode to Contact form 7 that takes say [next_week] and in the recived email the correct date is displayed.

Where and how do I create custom shortcodes to Contact form 7?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Add the following to your functions.php

```
wpcf7_add_shortcode('custom_date', 'wpcf7_custom_date_shortcode_handler', true);

function wpcf7_custom_date_shortcode_handler($tag) {
    if (!is_array($tag)) return '';

    $name = $tag['name'];
    if (empty($name)) return '';

    $next_week = date('Y-m-d', time() + (60*60*24*7)); 
    $html = '<input type="hidden" name="' . $name . '" value="' . $next_week . '" />';
    return $html;
}
```

Now in the "Form" field in CF7 GUI type `[custom_date next_week]`

Now you can use `[next_week]` in the message body.

Comment: I use a simpler version for my needs: `wpcf7_add_shortcode('input_name', function( $tag ) { return '<input name="'.$tag['basetype'].'" value="your_value" />' });`

Comment: `wpcf7_add_shortcode()` is deprecated, use `wpcf7_add_form_tag()` instead (although you will be warned if you have debug on).

Comment: @ChrisPink, wpcf7_add_form_tag() is not working, it just prints the short code as it is.

Comment: @divy3993 I believe this is a bug in 5.7.3

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit late to the response party, but I keep seeing this post when I want to add custom shortcodes to my forms and message body. I wanted to be able to insert shortcodes without registering them special in CF7 and often in the message body only (something CF7 doesn't seem to be able to do).

Here's how I finally did it:

```
// Allow custom shortcodes in CF7 HTML form
add_filter( 'wpcf7_form_elements', 'dacrosby_do_shortcodes_wpcf7_form' );
function dacrosby_do_shortcodes_wpcf7_form( $form ) {
    $form = do_shortcode( $form );
    return $form;
}

// Allow custom shortcodes in CF7 mailed message body
add_filter( 'wpcf7_mail_components', 'dacrosby_do_shortcodes_wpcf7_mail_body', 10, 2 );
function dacrosby_do_shortcodes_wpcf7_mail_body( $components, $number ) {
    $components['body'] = do_shortcode( $components['body'] );
    return $components;
};

// Add shortcode normally as per WordPress API
add_shortcode('my_code', 'my_code_callback');
function my_code_callback($atts){
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'foo' => 'bar'
    ), $atts));

    // do things
    return $foo;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two types of tags in CF7: *form tags* (the contact form itself) and [*mail tags*](https://contactform7.com/special-mail-tags/) (a email) — [read more](https://contactform7.com/tag-syntax/).

---

1. Custom **form tags**:

   To add a custom form tag you can use `wpcf7_add_form_tag()` function on `wpcf7_init` action hook ([Read more](https://contactform7.com/2015/01/10/adding-a-custom-form-tag/)).

   *The `wpcf7_add_shortcode()` function in the accepted answer is considered to be deprecated and replaced by this function.*
2. Custom **mail tags**:

   I didn't find any built-in functionality to add custom mail tags but I believe there are multiple possible workarounds here:

   1. Enable custom shortcodes (don't forget to create the shortcode handler beforehand):

      - For mail components, according to the [DACrosby's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13179355/wordpress-contact-form-7-custom-shortcodes/#33382282).
      - For entire mail (all components), using `wpcf7_special_mail_tags` filter:

   ```
   function my_special_mail_tag( $output, $name, $html ) {
       if ( 'myshortcode' === $name ) {
           $output = do_shortcode( "[$name]" );
       }
       return $output;
   }
   add_filter( 'wpcf7_special_mail_tags', 'my_special_mail_tag', 10, 3 );
   ```

   2. Add a custom hidden form tag with the prepopulated data to the form, and then use it in the mail: `[my-custom-form-tag-with-some-prepopulated-data]`; the custom form tag should be registered with the `wpcf7_add_form_tag()`, as specified above.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is simple. Do whatever shortcode you want and place it on contact form area. Just don't forget do the following:
Place only the following code in functions.php and your shortcode will work:

add_filter( 'wpcf7_form_elements', 'do_shortcode' );

Answer (score 0):

**Enable shortcodes inside the Form Template**

**Solution 1** - using `wpcf7_form_elements` filter

With the `wpcf7_form_elements` filter, we can modify the HTML output of the form. Since the output will contain shortcodes that were added in the Form Template, all we need to do is bind `do_shortcode` function as a callback to this filter inside `functions.php`, like so:

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_form_elements', 'do_shortcode' );
```

**Solution 2** - using Contact Form 7 Extension Plugin

If you are uncomfortable with editing functions.php file, there is a plugin available [Contact Form 7 Shortcode Enabler](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-shortcode-enabler/) that does exactly the same thing.

**Note:** Currently, the plugin latest update was 5 years ago but the plugin only executes the same line of code as in solution 1, so it should still work with the latest releases of WordPress.

**Enable shortcodes inside the Mail Template**

The `wpcf7_special_mail_tags` filter is used to customize the output of [form-tags](https://contactform7.com/tag-syntax/) and [special tags](https://contactform7.com/special-mail-tags/) of Contact Form 7. Luckily, this filter also detects the custom shortcodes that are found in the Mail Template as well, so we can use this filter to process those shortcodes too.

You need to add the following code inside the `functions.php` file:

```
function my_special_mail_tag( $output, $name, $html ) {
    if ( 'myshortcode' == $name )
        $output = do_shortcode( "[$name]" );
 
    return $output;
}
add_filter( 'wpcf7_special_mail_tags', 'my_special_mail_tag', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score -3):

I haven't do before, but I think that shortcodes are managed by wordpress itself (even for plugins as CF7).

An example to create a simple shortcode is:

```
//[foobar]
function foobar_func( $atts ){
 return "foo and bar";
}
add_shortcode( 'foobar', 'foobar_func' );
```

Placed in functions.php.

For more information: http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Or you can use a plugin like this that do the work: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/shortbus/

Comment: CF7 prints [foobar], posts and pages print "foo and bar". So it did not work.

Comment: This works fine when you would like to use the shortcode in the form but it does not work in the email beeing sent. Se my answer for the correct solution

Comment: This answer shows how to create a custom shortcode. Unfortunately, that was not the question being asked. The question was how to get a custom shortcode to be parsed in an email.